# Wait with return statement until Timer elapsed

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, wait

I have a method that returns a bool value, but should wait with returning the value until the System.Timers.Timer raises the elapsed event, because the value I want to return is set in the elapsed event of the timer.

```
public static bool RecognizePushGesture()
{
    List<Point3D> shoulderPoints = new List<Point3D>();
    List<Point3D> handPoints = new List<Point3D>();
    shoulderPoints.Add(Mouse.shoulderPoint);
    handPoints.Add(Mouse.GetSmoothPoint());
    Timer dt = new Timer(1000);
    bool click = false;

    dt.Elapsed += (o, s) =>
    {
        shoulderPoints.Add(Mouse.shoulderPoint);
        handPoints.Add(Mouse.GetSmoothPoint());
        double i = shoulderPoints[0].Z - handPoints[0].Z;
        double j = shoulderPoints[1].Z - handPoints[1].Z;
        double k = j - i;
        if (k >= 0.04)
        {
            click = true;
            dt.Stop();
        }
    };

    dt.Start();

    //should wait with returning the value until timer raises elapsed event
    return click;
}
```

Thanks, Tim

Comment: If you want to basically do something synchronously (block until it's completed) why are you starting a timer at all? What's the context here? (GUI, not GUI, what kind of GUI?)

Comment: If it'll be fired just once...why do you use a timer? If you don't mind to block the current thread you may use a Sleep() (or nothing at all). If you may do some other processing while waiting for the first "elapsed" event why don't use a thread/task (that you'll Join when finished with parallel work)?

Comment: ok, context is Kinect for Windows, i need to compare z coordinates of hand and shoulder joints with 1 second delay

Comment: i dont want the RecognizePushGesture() to block my current thread

Comment: @TimT RecognizePushGesture() caller will wait for its return value so it MUST wait. If it shouldn't you'd better to refactor caller too (and to don't use a timer in this case): make it asynchronous and replace the timer with a simple Thread.Sleep(1000).

Comment: tghats also a good idea thanks for your help guys

Comment: Alternative would be to let `RecognizePushGesture` take a delegate as parameter, which would work as callback whenever `k >= 0.04`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AutoResetEvent

```
public static bool RecognizePushGesture()
    {
        AutoResetEvent ar = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        List<Point3D> shoulderPoints = new List<Point3D>();
        List<Point3D> handPoints = new List<Point3D>();
        shoulderPoints.Add(Mouse.shoulderPoint);
        handPoints.Add(Mouse.GetSmoothPoint());
        Timer dt = new Timer(1000);
        bool click = false;
        dt.Elapsed += (o, s) =>
        {
            shoulderPoints.Add(Mouse.shoulderPoint);
            handPoints.Add(Mouse.GetSmoothPoint());
            double i = shoulderPoints[0].Z - handPoints[0].Z;
            double j = shoulderPoints[1].Z - handPoints[1].Z;
            double k = j - i;
            if (k >= 0.04)
            {
                click = true;
                dt.Stop();
            }
            ar.Set();
        };
        dt.Start();

        //should wait with returning the value until timer raises elapsed event
        ar.WaitOne();
        return click;
    }
```

Comment: ok problem solved just started RecognizePushGesture() in an own thread. this doesnt block my current thread anymore thanks for your help :)