# Is there any alternative in Kotlin for C#'s AutoResetEvent?

Tags: kotlin, autoresetevent

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13027138/17080993) where it uses this event and I would like to know if there is any similar alternative in Kotlin, since I would like to use the `WaitOne` method that it uses for the return.

Example code:

```
   fun exampleMethod(): String{

    var command = "example string"
    //do someting with this string

    return command

}
```

I want to run this method continuously and receive the value of my variable command of the return every time it runs on the loop.

Comment: I believe `AutoResetEvent` has nothing to do with Java - it is C# util. It would be easier if you described what do you try to achieve. Otherwise, only people who know both Kotlin and C# can help you.

Comment: My purpose is to create a loop that is executed every x time and that this includes the return statement. For example, if I create a timer, the loop is completed but the return is not included in the loop.

Comment: @RaceyT You mean you want to start a background task on a different thread? Your description of what you’re trying to do doesn’t match what AutoResetEvent is for.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the description of the AutoResetEvent, I want to start a background task that is running continuously. That is, a method that is executing continuously, including the return statement but I don't know how to do it

Comment: I don't really get this part about returning. It sounds to me like you need to run something continuously in the loop and return from it at the same time. Could you provide some kind of pseudo-code?

Comment: By reading `AutoResetEvent` docs briefly it sounds to me like a semaphore, but I'm not sure how does it relate to your problem.

Comment: I have added an explanation in my last edit of the post

Comment: @RaceyT I share the incomprehension of others here. Running the method continuously and returning a value from it seem to be mutually exclusive requirements. Could you please show some pseudo code of how you would expect that function to be used (from the caller's side)? When should the caller get a value back from the function call? How do you expect it to get such a return value multiple times? It seems that you might want to return a `Flow` or take a callback parameter instead of actually returning a value.

Comment: My intention is to get the return value every x time continuously and store this value in a model. In a different class, I want to show the value stored in the model, and that this value get updated every time the method that is running continuously is executed.

Answer (score 0):

So I just ran into a situation like this and was missing my good old `AutoResetEvent`. Kotlin does have great coroutine controls like Flows that can be used for signalling. I made a class that wraps this design pattern so its purpose is easier to read when used.

```kotlin
/** A coroutine synchronization event that suspends coroutines until a signal is sent. */
class SyncSignal(signaled: Boolean = false) {
    private val signal = MutableStateFlow(signaled)
    private val filteredSignal = signal.filter { it }.take(1)
    /** Suspend the current coroutine until it recieves a signal to resume */
    suspend fun await() = filteredSignal.collect()
    /** Sets the state to signaled allowing one or more coroutines to resume */
    fun signal() = signal.compareAndSet(expect = false, update = true)
    /** Resets the state to nonsignaled, causing coroutines to suspend */
    suspend fun reset() = signal.compareAndSet(expect = true, update = false)
}

val event = SyncSignal()
runBlocking { 
    launch {
        println("Wait 1")
        delay(200)
        event.await()
        println("1")
    }
    launch {
        println("Wait 2")
        delay(100)
        event.await()
        println("2")
    }
    launch {
        delay(300)
        println("RELEASE!")
        event.signal()
        event.reset()
        event.await()
        println("Tada!")
    }
    launch {
        delay(400)
        event.signal()
    }
}
/*
Wait 1
Wait 2
RELEASE!
2
1
Tada!
*/
```

Let me know if you can see any issues with the implementation. I tried making an AutoSyncSignal, but I ran into a lot of issues trying to get the first awaiting coroutine to reset the signal without getting dead-locked.

You can try it on the [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/Uw9Juh31L_)